# Why do we drink wine on Shabbat?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Why do we drink wine on Shabbat when it's stated in the Kiddush (כִּי הוּא **יוֹם תְּחִלָּה**) that this is a day of tequila?

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 5):

It's because of the double gezeiras-shav. Yom Kippur is referred to as Shabbos Shabason, and Yom Kippur itself is only ki-purim. So the halakhic wine from Purim is transferred to Shabbos. But since ein mikra yotzei midei peshuto, tequila is still a recommended drink between courses (or anytime one's spouse goes into the kitchen to get something). But it is also a Binyan Av so any hard alcohol or mixed drink suffices for this purpose.

Answer (score 4):

Confusing a *chet* with a *kuf* is a stretch, here. But, I'll go along...

This phrase is said during Friday night Kiddush, and the phrase you quoted says **yom** tequilla. It is talking about the daytime only when you have tequilla. At night time, you still need wine.